# Vue JS lodash findKey nested object with dot notation returns undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm trying to pull out a value for a nested object key from some eligibility array that I've got, but I'm getting an undefined value for some reason and need to know what I'm missing.

Given the following array:

```js
const eligibilityCriteria = [
  { field: 'loan.amount', operator: '>=', value: 1000 },
  { field: 'loan.term', operator: '>=', value: 1 },
  { field: 'applicant.birthday', operator: '>=', value: 40 },
  { field: 'applicant.isHomeowner', operator: '==', value: false }
]
```

I need to find `loan.amount` from a nested object and pull out it's value:

My big nested object is *(coming from the store)*

```js
application: {
  meta: {
    brand: '',
    version: '',
    affiliate: '',
    affiliate_full: '',
    campaign: '',
    client_hostname: '',
    client_href: '',
    client_origin: '',
    client_useragent: '',
    client_ip: '127.0.0.1',
    icicle_hash: ''
  },
  loan: {
    amount: 500,
    term: null,
    purpose: null
  }
}
```

My function right now is:

```js
checkEligibility () {
  const eligibilityCriteria = [
    { field: 'loan.amount', operator: '>=', value: 1000 },
    { field: 'loan.term', operator: '>=', value: 1 },
    { field: 'applicant.birthday', operator: '>=', value: 40 },
    { field: 'applicant.isHomeowner', operator: '==', value: false }
  ]

  for (const [index, offer] of this.datasets.offers.entries()) {
    const eligibility = eligibilityCriteria

    if (eligibility) {
      for (const [ci, criteria] of eligibility.entries()) {

        // TODO: this fails to pull the value, returns undefined
        const field = _.findKey(this.$store.state.application.application, criteria.field)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of lodash are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to misunderstood what `_.findKey()` [does](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findKey)

> This method is like _.find except that it returns the key of the first element predicate returns truthy for instead of the element itself.

See **Example 2** in the code below.

If you want to retrieve the value from the object at a given path, you must use [_.property()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#property) (Example 2 below)

```js
const eligibilityCriteria = [
  { field: 'loan.amount', operator: '>=', value: 1000 },
  { field: 'loan.term', operator: '>=', value: 1 },
]

const application = {
  loan: {
    amount: 500,
    term: 2,
    amount2: 0,
  }
}

// example 1
// outputs "loan"
console.log(_.findKey(application, "amount"))     
// outputs undefined - there is no key in application object that has property chain "loan.amount"
console.log(_.findKey(application, "loan.amount"))
//  outputs undefined - "amount2" key is there but the value is falsy
console.log(_.findKey(application, "amount2"))     

// example 2
for (const [ci, criteria] of eligibilityCriteria.entries()) {
  console.log(criteria.field, _.property(criteria.field)(application))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```